# Convergence of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\frac 12 (x^2 - (1-a)^2)}}{\sqrt{a^2 + x^2}\sqrt{(1-a)^2 + x^2}}dx, \ a<0$

Tags: convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I came across the following integral
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\frac 12 (x^2 - (1-a)^2)}}{\sqrt{a^2 + x^2}\sqrt{(1-a)^2 + x^2}}dx, \quad a<0.$$

Can it be proven that the integral converge for every $a<0$?

**EDIT**

Just a thought, kinda looks like a chi distribution, maybe.

Comment: Yes as the integrand is continuous on any compact and is equivalent to $$C \frac{e^{-1/2 x^2}}{x^2}$$ when $x \to \pm \infty$.

Comment: I see your point thanks. @Delta-u

Comment: This undoubtedly converges. The $e^{-x^2} $ term in the numerator isn't even necessary to achieve convergence away from origin, since the denominator is clearly $\mathcal{O}(x^2)$